# Vaadin 14 max rows number in textarea

Tags: components, textarea, vaadin, vaadin14

Is there any option to set max rows/height of textarea and when it would exceed it then component will stop getting new characters like in maxLength? i dont want the scrollbar to show up. I cant use maxLength couse when i`m adding new lines by pressing Enter then text area can exceed max rows.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no feature like that as of now. You should comment in this GitHub discussion: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/1399 with your use case and requirements.

Comment: so maybe is there any option to cut label/text/span if it exceed some height? Couse i`m working on component where on double clicking at text i cane change it  and save again, but when user add many enters then my text will be exceeding component height. i want to let the user use newline any way he want.